# Conditional styling menu in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I need to style main menu which is in header.php depending if I am on font page or blog `(is_home(),is_front_page())`.

How can I do that without rendering completely different menu, changing only style in css file?

Answer (score 0):

You can make your CSS selectors more specific to target elements that only land on the front and blog pages, since certain classes are given to the `<body>` tag on those pages:

```
#my-menu > ul > li {
    /* Some styles */
}
```

Would become:

```
body.home #my-menu > ul > li {
    /* Some styles only to be applied on the front page */
}

body.blog #my-menu > ul > li {
    /* Some styles only to be applied on the blog page */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**edit:** @George solution is the best for your case. For those are looking for something more customizable, keep reading.

You can add your own custom field on each post/page, check if the current page has this custom field and it's value in `header.php` (see [get_query_var](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var)) and append your own class to body `<body <?php body_class('your-class') ?>>`

With this you will be able to have different themes for different pages just adding a custom field.